# Как оптимизировать создание контейнеров?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, gui

В теле цикла мне нужно создать довольно много контейнеров с абсолютно одинаковыми характеристиками, но разным наполнением.

Сейчас это происходит в три этапа:

1. Создается `QWidget`
2. Задаются определенные внешние характеристики для `QWidget`
3. Создается новый контейнер, который привязывается к `QWidget`

Цикл повторяется некоторое количество раз (всегда разное).

Мне стало интересно, может быть, можно заранее сделать шаблон для контейнера и не пересоздавать его каждый раз снова? Если это возможно, пожалуйста, помогите мне оптимизировать код.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.make()

    def make(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet(box_qss)
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            song_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            self.main_box.addWidget(container)        


box_qss = '''QWidget {
                 background-color: #1F252F;
                 border-radius: 5px;
             }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPD:** В каждом контейнере будет кнопка и две надписи(текст каждой надписи будет отличаться):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.make()

    def make(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet(box_qss)
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            song_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            self.main_box.addWidget(container)

            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
            btn.setStyleSheet(btn_qss)
            song_box.addWidget(btn)

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
            label.setStyleSheet(label_qss)
            song_box.addWidget(label)

            duration = QtWidgets.QLabel('00:00')
            duration.setStyleSheet(label_qss)
            song_box.addWidget(duration)


box_qss = '''QWidget {
                 background-color: #1F252F;
                 border-radius: 5px;
             }'''

label_qss = '''QLabel {
                   color: white;
               }'''

btn_qss = '''QPushButton {
                 background-color: #3A4256;
                 color: white;
             }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вы сильно упростили пример, чтобы понять что в нем можно оптимизировать. Добавьте в пример, то что вы пишите: `но разным наполнением` и `Цикл повторяется некоторое количество раз(всегда разное).`

Comment: @S.Nick, я написал то, что должно быть в контейнерах. Но, к сожалению, не могу тут воссоздать ситуацию с числом повторов цикла. Как вы знаете, я делаю музыкальный плеер. Эти контейнеры будут создаваться для каждой песни музыкального альбома. Число этих песен хранится в базе данных. Я никак не влияю на их количество. Оптимизация не обязательна. Если она не сыграет большой роли, можно и не менять код. Просто мне показалось странным, что я так делаю :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил попробовать так:

```
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, list_album, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.song_box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.song_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        for i, text in enumerate(list_album):
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"Button {i+1}", 
                minimumWidth=70,             
                minimumHeight=50,
                clicked=lambda ch, t=text[0]: self.onButton(t))  
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
                f'{text[0]} - {text[1]}', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

            self.song_box.addWidget(button, i, 0)
            self.song_box.addWidget(label, i, 1)

    def onButton(self, text):
        print(f"Выбрали песню {text}")


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, music_album, parent = None):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.music_album = music_album
        self.container = None

        self.main_box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выберите Music Album', minimumHeight=50, clicked=self.make)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.button, 111, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

    def make(self):
        num_album = randint(1, len(self.music_album))    # выбираем случайный альбом
        list_album = self.music_album[num_album]
        if self.container:
            self.container.deleteLater()

        self.container = Widget(list_album, self)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.container, 1, 0)



qss = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: #1F252F;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
QLabel {
    color: white;
}
QPushButton {
    background-color: #3A4256;
    color: white;
}
'''

# Какие-то альбомы с какими-то песнями
music_album = {
1: (('Text1', '00:00'), ('Text2', '00:02'), ('Text3', '00:03'), ('Text4', '00:04'), ('Text5', '00:05'),),
2: (('Text21', '00:00'), ('Text22', '00:02'), ('Text23', '00:03'), ('Text24', '00:03'),),
3: (('Text31', '00:00'), ('Text32', '00:02'), ('Text33', '00:03'), ),
4: (('Text41', '00:00'), ('Text42', '00:02'),),
5: (('Text51', '00:00'),),
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                          # <<<=====<
    window = MyWindow(music_album)
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.resize(250, 370)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть вопросы, пишите, я прокомментирую.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я думал, вы уже забыли :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 я все помню и все вижу, но торопить меня не надо :)